# why does my loop prints out the same thing forever?

Tags: c

I am trying to make a loop that if you type multiples of three, the program prints (1) and the loop goes on. Else, you get (0) and the loop ends. But, if I type 3, it prints out (1) forever.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(1){
        if(n % 3 != 0){
            printf("(0)\n");
            break;
        }else{
            printf("(1)\n");
            continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're scanning just once. Move `scanf` line under `while`.

Comment: What do you mean by "and the loop goes on" in your description of what it should do?

Answer (score 1):

proper code for the above problem would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
    int n;

    while(1){
        
        printf("enter n value");
        scanf("%d", &n);
        if(n%3!= 0){
            printf("(0)\n");
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("(1)\n");
          continue;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```